# updating mongodb using $push operator in angular-meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I am trying to push arrays from one collection to another.
this is the code I used in my server js

```
    updateSettings: function(generalValue) {
     let userId = Meteor.userId();
       let settingsDetails = GeneralSettings.findOne({
   "_id": generalValue
 });
            Meteor.users.update({
     _id: userId
   }, {
     $push: {

       "settings._id": generalValue,
       "settings.name": settingsDetails.name,
       "settings.description": settingsDetails.description,
       "settings.tag": settingsDetails.tag,
        "settings.type": settingsDetails.type,
       "settings.status": settingsDetails.status
     }


   })

}
```

updateSettings is the meteor method. GeneralSettings is the first collection and user is the second collection. I want to push arrays from GeneralSettings to users collection. While I try this the result i got is like

```
 "settings" : {
    "_id" : [ 
        "GdfaHPoT5FXW78aw5", 
        "GdfaHPoT5FXW78awi"

    ],
    "name" : [ 
        "URL", 
        "TEXT" 

    ],
    "description" : [ 
        "https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/", 
        "this is a random text" 

    ],
    "tag" : [ 
        "This is a demo of an Url selected", 
        "demo for random text"
    ],
    "type" : [ 
        "url", 
        "text"
    ],
    "status" : [ 
        false, 
        false
    ]
}
```

But the output I want is

```
 "settings" : {
    "_id" : "GdfaHPoT5FXW78aw5",

    "name" :  "URL", 

    "description" :  
        "https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/", 

    "tag" :"This is a demo of an Url selected", 

    "type" :  "url",


    "status" :    false 



},
```

What changes to be made in my server.js inorder to get this output

Comment: Try using `$set` instead of `$push` here. You push to arrays, but I don't think `settings._id`, for example, is an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one case where you "do not want" to use "dot notation". The [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator expects and `Object` or is basically going to add the "right side" to the array named in the "left side key":

```
// Make your life easy and just update this object
settingDetails._id = generalValue;

// Then you are just "pushing" the whole thing into the "settings" array
Meteor.users.update(
  { _id: userId }, 
  { "$push": { "settings": settingDetails } }
)
```

When you used "dot notation" on each item, then that is asking to create "arrays" for "each" of the individual "keys" provided. So it's just "one" array key, and the object to add as the argument.